# Knowing if all input boxes are empty in ES5 (what is the ES5 equivalent of this ES6?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

Trying to know if all input boxes with an ID starting with 'txtYear_' are empty.  I have the following ES6 code, but I would like a ES5 equivalent:

Thanks!

```js
let allNotEmpty = Array.from($("[id^='txtYear_']")).every(function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";    
})

console.log(allNotEmpty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function from jQuery.

```js
var allNotEmpty = true;

$("[id^='txtYear_']").each(function(i, el) {
    allNotEmpty = allNotEmpty && el.value !== "";
});

console.log(allNotEmpty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `call` to apply `Array#every` to any array-like object:

```
var allNotEmpty = Array.prototype.every.call($("[id^='txtYear_']"), function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";    
});
```

Side note: selectors like `$("[id^='txtYear_']")` are a good sign you should be using a class instead.